# Customize SuiteBarLinks without removing NewsFeed, SkyDrive, and Sites

Tags: development

I want to customize the suitebar links and I already did with a delegate control the only thing is that it removes the existing links, newsfeed, skydrives and sites and I want to keep them

```
public partial class SuiteLinksDelegateCtrl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Style);
            writer.Write(".ms-core-suiteLinkList {display: inline-block;}");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "ms-core-suiteLinkList");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);
            AddSuiteLink(writer, "http://learningsharepoint.com", "App1", "Lsp");
            AddSuiteLink(writer, "http://learningsharepoint.com", "App2", "Lsp");
            AddSuiteLink(writer, "http://learningsharepoint.com", "App3", "Lsp");

            writer.RenderEndTag();
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        protected static void AddSuiteLink(HtmlTextWriter writer, string url, string name, string linkId)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "ms-core-suiteLink");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "ms-core-suiteLink-a");
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, url);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, linkId);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "ms-verticalAlignMiddle");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            writer.Write(name);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am missing your delegate XML, but it should be a matter of altering the Sequence attribute of the Control. Try increasing it by one, to see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy already did everything for me.  I can put links before, and after, I can hide the default links if I want, or not, this solution is almost perfect

http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-adding-links-suite-bar-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-overriding-suitelinksdelegate-delegate-control/